# if and elseif conditions are not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I made an IQ Test on JavaScript and gave conditions for the score that for certain ranges it displays different IQ scores but no matter how many correct answers it only displays the last condition. I've tried so many things but nothing is working. I need to submit this project soon. I would be very grateful if someone could help. I have attached relevant part of code below.

```js
  
 

 function displayResult() 
{  
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

    var correct = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectOptions.length; i++) 
    {

      if (selectOptions[i] === allQuestions[i].answer) {

        correct++ ;

        console.log(correct)
      }
    }

    if (correct < 5){
      score.append("Your IQ Score lies in the range of 70-79 which is classified as Bordeline. 6.7% of the world's population falls in this range.<br> <img id='img1' src='BORDERLINE.png' height=90px width=500px/></br>");


    }else if (correct>=5 && correct < 10){
      score.append("Your IQ Score lies in the range of 80-89 which is classified as low average. 16.1% of the world's population falls in this range. <br> <img id='img1' src='LOW AVERAGE.png' height=90px width=500px/></br> ");

    }else if (correct >= 10 && correct < 20){

      score.append("Your IQ Score lies in the range of 90-109 which is
 
 classified as average. 50% of the world's population falls in this range. <br>

 <img id='img1' src='AVERAGE.png' height=90px width=500px/></br>");

    }else if (correct >= 20 && correct <=25){

      score.append("Your IQ Score lies in the range of 110-119 which is 

        classified as high average. 16.1% of the world's population falls in 

         this range. <br> <img id='img1' src='HIGH AVERAGE.png' height=90px 
         width=500px/></br>"); 

    }else if(correct >= 25 && correct <=30) {

       score.append("Your IQ Score lies in the range of 119-129 which is 

       classified as superior. 6.7% of the world's population falls in this
 
        range. 
       <br> <img id='img1' src='SUPERIOR.png' height=90px width=500px/> 

       </br>");  }
   
          
    return score;    
   
  }
```

```html
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Make Quiz Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Quiz Website Using JavaScript</h1>
            <br/>
            <div id="quiz"></div>
              <p id="countdown">30:00</p></h1>
            <div class="button" id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></div>
            <div class="button" id="prev"><a href="#">Prev</a></div> 
        </div>
        

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="quiz.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your first condition `correct == 0 && correct < 5`  seems to need to be  using `||` instead of `&&` because if `correct == 0`, then it is already `<5`.

Comment: if (correct = 0 && correct <= 5){ ?

Comment: yea I meant correct>=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This part should be changed for it to make any sense.**

```
if (correct = 0 && correct <= 5){
          score.append("YOUR IQ SCORES LIES IN THE RANGE OF 70 and 79 WHICH IS CLASSIFIED AS BORDERLINE <img src='img9b.png'/>");
}
```

**Something like this.**

```
if (correct <= 5) {
    score.append("YOUR IQ SCORE IS IN THE RANGE OF 70 and 79 WHICH IS CLASSIFIED AS BORDERLINE <img src='img9b.png'/>");
} else if (correct <= 10) {
    score.append("YOUR IQ SCORE IS IN THE RANGE OF 80 and 119 WHICH IS CLASSIFIED AS AVERAGE <img src='img9b.png'/>");
} else {
    score.append("YOUR IQ SCORE IS ABOVE AVERAGE <img src='img9b.png'/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(correct = 0 && correct <= 5)` will *set* `correct` to 0. It will not *test* it against 0. Even if you mean `correct == 0 && correct <= 5`, that's redundant since 0 is always <= 5.

Perhaps you meant `correct >= 0 && correct <= 5`?